# What are my choices of technologies for GP development on Intel integrated GPU's?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, intel

What are my choices of technologies, languages and tools to develop general-purpose software running on the integrated GPUs of Intel Ivy Bridge processors?  OpenCL (if so, Intel drivers?  Whose compiler?)? CUDA?  Something based on LLVM?

I believe DirectCompute is not an option for us, because we won't be running windows.

**Edit**: Just found [this article](http://vr-zone.com/articles/ivy-bridge-hd-graphics-to-gain-4k-display-support-in-october/17173.html) that suggests that OpenCL support is coming in the IvyBridge drivers shortly.

Comment: For what i know only IvyBridge video get support for OpenCL. SandyBridge and below only have support for OpenCL-on-CPU, not OpenCL-on-GPU. Microsoft was doing some c++ extensions for SIMD calculation, but dunno if it was released, more so supported by non-MS toolchains. Nvidia would actively prohibit outside CUDA. There was once CUDA driver for AMD Radeon videocards, then nVidia managed to kill that project.

Comment: There is currently no solution if you aren't running Windows.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming there's at least one solution: shoehorning your code into OpenGL shaders :).

Comment: @brooks94: Even there your are stuck at about OpenGL 2.1 and shader support is very limited

Comment: @brooks94: OpenCL support for ivy bridge isn't coming soon, it has been available for almost 6 months. But for the second time, it is Windows only.

Comment: @Arioch 'The: small correction, NVIDIA has encouraged 3rd parties to support CUDA applications on other processors by releasing the source code for the CUDA compiler and contributing it to LLVM (http://bit.ly/KMfY6h, http://bit.ly/QjGrMx). I haven’t heard of AMD trying to support CUDA on Radeon, can you point me to any information on this?

Comment: @Arloch: I know NVIDIA have been actively supporting the [gpuocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) project, and that includes a dynamic PTX assembler to IL backend for CUDA code to run on AMD GPUs.

Comment: @Tom: There is a project called [GPU Ocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot) translating NVIDIA PTX kernels into intermediate language and then transforms them to AMD CAL to make it runnable on AMD GPUs. But, unfortunately, my first attempt shows it does not work at this job!

Comment: @Tom AMD was not - instead it also suppressed that independent effort, pushing for finalizing then-drafted OpenCL and DirectCompute specifications, rather then competing on NVidia proprietary field. You can find the traces of the project at videodrivers related forums like http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/272428-15-cuda It was before OpenCL 1.0 specs even released.

Comment: @Arioch'The: That's kind of my point, I'm just saying that NVIDIA are encouraging 3rd party efforts, including contributing to gpuocelot as talonmies pointed out.

Comment: @Tom, I just didn't knew it. So now that OpenCL and DirectCompute are getting steam and going to make CUDA obsolete - hey try to push CUDA everywhere and save their investments from oblivion. Well, nice try. But back when CUDA was like the only practical API (Dx9 shaders were very limited) they acted completely opposing ways.

Answer (score 1):

As @talonmies points out, on Intel OpenCL is supported on the integrated GPU, but only on Windows:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-sdk-frequently-asked-questions/#14

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL-ES is running good on intel HD processors.